# Javacc for parsing '<UPPER_CASE> <ARROW>

Tags: javacc

I am writing a parser for a set of CFG.
(Note: The RHS can ONLY be an uppercase letter)

/*ignore declaration and stuff, here's the main part of the code */

```
void
start():
{
}
{
    (
     <UPPER_CHAR>
     <ARROW>
     <STRING>
     ( <PIPE> <STRING> )*
    )*
}


TOKEN:
{
 <ARROW: "=>" >
|
 <PIPE: "|">
|
 <UPPER_CHAR: (["A"-"Z"])>
}

TOKEN: {<STRING: (<LETTER> |  <DIGIT> | <SYMBOL>)+ > }
```

This obviously missed some edge cases, some which include:

`A => A | a | D E => e`

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess SYMBOL includes "=" and ">" but not "|".  In that case. STRING will match the whole of " D E => e".

Why do you want STRING at all?  Why not do something like this.

```
void start() : {} {
   (
      <UPPER_CHAR> <ARROW>
      choices()
   )*
}
void choices() : {} {
      choice() ( <PIPE> choice())*
}
void choice() : {} {
    LOOKAHEAD(<UPPER_CHAR> <ARROW> )
    {}
 |
    (<UPPER_CHAR> | <LOWER_CHAR>) choice()
 |
    {}
}
```

The reason I used recursion for `choice` is that there is no way to use syntactic lookahead to exit a loop.  I.e. what you want is  `(<UPPER_CHAR> | <LOWER_CHAR>)*`, but you want to get out of this loop as soon as the next two tokens are `<UPPER_CHAR> <ARROW>`.